# Can you create a list based on the output of bools from another class?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

Edited for (hopefully clarity):

What I am looking to do (and not sure if it can be done) is in this order:

1. Determine if variables are/are not present (eg, "Do you have a mouse? Do you have a keyboard? Do you have Speakers? etc.)
2. Using the output from #1, create a list that incorporates the outputs from the are/are not statement (eg, Do you have a mouse? Yes? Okay Add mouse to the list. Do you have a keyboard? No? Okay, omit the keyboard from the same list as the mouse and do not add it to another list. Do you have speakers? Yes? Add speakers to the same list that the mouse is in.
3. Be able to reference this list at a later point.

If the code below confuses you, please don't let it and instead look at #1-3 instead.

Edit2: This is for C# w/ Target Framework .NET Framework 4.7.2, Output type Class Library(.dll), in case that changes how the code needs to be written.

```
public class AreFooPresent
{
     public static bool foo0 = false
     public static bool foo1 = false
     public static bool foo2 = false
}

public class AreTheyThereList
    {
        List<FooList> myList = new List<FooList>
        {
            myList.Add(new FooList(if return foo0 != false));
            myList.Add(new FooList(if return foo1 != false));
            myList.Add(new FooList(if return foo2 != false));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remove `return`, refer to `foo0` etc as `AreFooPresent.foo0`, move the `if (...)` statements _outside_ the `FooList()` constructor and the `myList.Add()` call, and do this in a constructor

Comment: if you use reflection you can do it even independetly of how many `bool`s you have

Comment: the question is not very clear, Add what to the list? "the bool from a previous class returns true", what previous class? do you mean the previous object? And classes does not return anything, methods return things, and classes can have fields/properties.  What is the actual goal you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: What is a `FooList` when it's at home? What does `bool from a previous class` mean? `have the conditionals added in without effecting the rest of the list` Added into what, and what is the rest of the list? Please [edit] your question and elaborate

Comment: @JonasH and CharlieFace I edited the question, hopefully that makes it more clear. I get that the code might be confusing since I am so new to C# I don't know how to code it correctly (if I did I wouldn't be asking the question right? lol)

Comment: IMHO define `[HasFlags] enum Peripherals {Mouse = (1<<0), Speaker = (1<<1), ...}` instead of a collection of bools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another one using linq

```cs
using System.Linq;
...
var list = (new bool[] {AreFooPresent.foo0, AreFooPresent.foo1, AreFooPresent.foo2})
    .Where(b => b).ToList();
```

And I see you initializing some object `FooList`, in this case something like

```cs
using System.Linq;
...
var list = (new bool[] {AreFooPresent.foo0, AreFooPresent.foo1, AreFooPresent.foo2})
    .Where(b => b)
    .Select(b => new FooList(b)).ToList();
```

Comment: What does the `.Where(b => b)` do?

Comment: This task would be easier, if the `AreFooPresent` class had a property returning a `IEnumerable<bool>`.

Comment: @SAR `where` selects items that match certain condition. `(b => b)` - `b` on the left is the item, which is `bool`. `b` on the right is same as `b == true`. You get in plain English "where boolean item equals to true"

Comment: @SAR, the `b` before the `=>` introduces a variable representing all the foos in the list. The `b` after the `=>` is a Boolean expression telling the `Where` extension method whether to include an element in the output. Since `b` is a Boolean expression by itself, no expression like `b == true` is required. `b => b` is a short hand expression (lambda expression) for `bool Func(bool b) { return b; }`. It is applied to each element of the enumeration.

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes and T.S, thank you both!

Comment: @SAR, `b => b` looks strange, but another example makes it clearer: `IEnumerable<int> evenIntegers = listOfIntegers.Where(i => i % 2 == 0);` where `%` is the modulo operator and yields the remainder of the integer division `i / 2`.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to SO! Something simple like the code below does the job. It'll only add to the list IF it's true and as they're static members, you can reference the class then the static members.

Then at the end, it'll return the list of positive bools (if any) - if not, it'll be  an empty list.

```
    public class AreFooPresent 
    {
      public static bool foo0 = false
      public static bool foo1 = false
      public static bool foo2 = false
    }
    
    public class AreTheyThereList 
    {
      public List<bool> MyPositiveFooCollectionMethod() 
      {
        List<bool>myList = new List<FooList>();
    
        if (AreFooPresent.foo0) myList.Add(AreFooPresent.foo0);
        if (AreFooPresent.foo1) myList.Add(AreFooPresent.foo1);
        if (AreFooPresent.foo2) myList.Add(AreFooPresent.foo2);
    
        return myList;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Unfortunately though when I added this to the program (just copy/paste to see how it would look) I got error `CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<FooList>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<bool>'`